# How to write text into sap.m.Input with UIVeri5?

Tags: sapui5, uiveri5

When writing a test for an [SAP UI5](https://ui5.sap.com/) application with [UIVeri5](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5): How can I enter programmatically some text into an element of type [sap.m.Input](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.Input)? I tried it with method `inputKeys` as follows:

```
it("should enter some text", function() {

    let inputElement = element(by.control({
        viewName   : "com.example.myapp.View.main",
        controlType: "sap.m.Input"
    }));
    expect( inputElement ).toBeDefined(); // is okay

    inputElement.sendKeys("Some Text"); // fails!

    // ...
});
```

The element is found, but the statement `inputElement.sendKeys("Some Text")` fails with the following error:

```
 Control Element sap.m.Input#__xmlview0--myInput has no dom representation
```

I cannot find any other method in Protractor's [ElementFinder](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) which seems to be suitable to achieve this.

Comment: The [README file](https://github.com/mide42/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/README.md) in UIVeri5's repository on GitHub suggests to create a questions on stackoverflow with tag `uiver5`; however, this tag is not created so far and [you need a reputation score of at least 1500](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294723/1364368) (which I don't have) to create it.

Comment: sendKeys() is the correct way, very similar to Protractor. What version of UI5 do you use ?. You use latest UIVeri5 right ?.

Comment: Version of UI5 is 1.60.7, version of UIVeri5 is 1.40.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In found out that when adding `interaction: "focus"` to the selector it works:

```
let inputElement = element(by.control({
    viewName   : "com.example.myapp.View.main",
    controlType: "sap.m.Input",
    interaction: "focus" // this is new!
}));

inputElement.sendKeys("Some Text"); // works
```

See also the [section on "Interaction Adapters"](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/docs/usage/locators.md#interaction-adapters) in UIVeri5's documentation.

Comment: This is a workaround of a a bug we once had in uiveri5/opanui5. In recent UI5 and recent UIVeri5, this is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I found a **workaround** for my issue, namely to use the Protractor method `by.id()` to reference the `sap.m.Input` element by its generated ID:

```
let inputElement = element( by.id("__xmlview0--myInput-inner") ); 

inputElement.sendKeys("Some Text"); // now it works
```

However, I consider this as workaround and no as solution, because [UIVeri5's documentation](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/docs/usage/locators.md) says "Avoid ID Locators that Use Generated IDs".

Comment: Using generated ID is a recepie for disaster - imagine ui5 devs add one more button in some complex control like ObjectPage. Then all generated IDs for controls of this type on this page will change. Or similarly, imagine you adding/removing button in this view.